# Image stretched and overflowing from the container

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

[image][image]I am trying to add an image to sit within the contact form and be same height as the rest of the contents inside the container but how it is coded now the image is stretched vertically outside of the container  and does not properly fit . I have tried overflow options not working,I have added this plug in on the Tailwindcss configuration page, plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')] nothing I try seems to be fixing this here is my code :

EDIT: the first pic is what it should look like and the second is the actual

```
<section>
      <div className="h-screen items-center flex justify-center">
        <form

          className="bg-white flex rounded-lg w-1/2 font-burtons"
        >
          <div className="flex-1 text-gray-700  p-20">
            <h1 className="text-3xl pb-2 text-teal-600 font-burtons">
              Let's get started 
            </h1>
            <p className="text-lg  text-gray-500">
              Join our E-learning platform today and unlock over 500+ courses
              and digital assets ready to download.
            </p>
            <div className="mt-6 ">
              {/* Name input field */}
              <div className="pb-4">
                <label className='block font-burtons text-sm pb-2'
                  htmlFor="name">


                </label>

                <input
                  className="border-2 border-gray-500 p-2 rounded-md w-1/2 focus:border-teal-500 focus:ring-teal-500 "
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  placeholder="Enter your name"

                />
              </div>
              {/* Email input field */}
              <div className="pb-4">
                <label
                  className=" block font-burtons text-sm pb-2"
                  htmlFor='email'>
                </label>

                <p></p>
                <input
                  className="border-2 border-gray-500 p-2 rounded-md w-1/2 focus:border-teal-500 focus:ring-teal-500"
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Enter your email address"

                />
              </div>
              {/* Country input field */}
              <div className="pb-4">
                <label

                  className="block font-burtons text-sm pb-2"
                  htmlFor='country'
                >

                </label>
                <select
                  className="border-2 border-gray-500 p-2 rounded-md w-1/2 focus:border-teal-500 focus:ring-teal-500"
                  name="country"

                >
                  <option>United States</option>
                  <option>United Kingdom</option>
                  <option>Germany</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              {/* Terms of service*/}
              <div className="pb-4">
                <label className='block font-burtons text-sm pb-2'
                  htmlFor='terms'>


                </label>

                <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="terms"
                    value="checked"

                    className="h-5 w-5 text-teal-500 border-2  background-gray-500 focus:border-teal-500 focus:ring-teal-500"
                  />
                  <p className="text-sm font-burtons gray-500">
                    I agree to the Terms and Service
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="bg-teal-500 font-burtons text-sm text-white py-3 mt-6 rounded-lg w-full"
              >
                Start learning today!
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='flex-1 relative'>
            <Image src={formImage} fill className='object-cover overflow-auto' />

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
 </main>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could try the `object-contain` class.

Comment: Yep tried that, did not help . Thanks though

Comment: Without having a complete reproducible example it's hard to help, but you could try to inspect the image element in the browser dev tools, and see how the computed styles are applied and where they come from.